# c++ Как в новом списке чтобы не печатало количество введенных элементов и в новом списке отображалась дробная часть

Tags: c++, visual-c++

У меня программа работает правильно, но при выводе нового списка выходит в печать и введенное количество элементов и в новом списке не удаляет одинаковые вещественные числа и не отображается дробная часть, только целая. Что отображается есть на фото: как это убрать "6" и чтобы выходило не "2" два раза, а один раз "2,12". Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <Windows.h> 

using namespace std;

struct node // узел
{
    int inf;
    node* next;
};

struct list // список
{
    node* head = nullptr;

    list(int n)
    {
        head = new node;
        head->inf = n;
        head->next = nullptr;
    }

    void clear() // очистка
    {
        node* ptr1 = head, * ptr2 = head->next;
        while (ptr2)
        {
            ptr1 = ptr2;
            ptr2 = ptr2->next;
            delete ptr1;
        }
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
    }

    ~list()
    {
        (*this).clear();
    }

    void add(int n) // добавление
    {
        node* ptr = head;
        if (ptr)
        {
            while (ptr->next)
                ptr = ptr->next;
            ptr->next = new node;
            ptr->next->inf = n;
            ptr->next->next = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            head = new node;
            head->inf = n;
            head->next = nullptr;
        }
    }

    void print() // печать
    {
        node* ptr = head;
        if (ptr)
        {
            while (ptr)
            {
                cout << ptr->inf << ' ';
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            cout << '\n';
        }
        else cout << "Нет элементов\n";
    }

    void remove_duplicates() // удаление повторяющихся элементов
    {
        node* current = head;
        node* next_next;
        if (current == NULL)
            return;
        while (current->next != NULL)
        {
            if (current->inf == current->next->inf)
            {
                next_next = current->next->next;
                delete(current->next);
                current->next = next_next;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int n;

    printf("\nВведите количество элементов: ");
    cin >> n;
    list lst(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        float element;
        cout << "Введите элемент " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> element;
        lst.add(element);
    }
    lst.print();
    lst.remove_duplicates();
    printf("\nНовый список: ");
    lst.print();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

А что не так?

```
float element;
cin >> element;
lst.add(element);
```

Передаем. Но так как

```
struct node // узел
{
    int inf;
```

да и

```
void add(int n) // добавление
```

то, понятно, дробная часть отбрасывается...

Что до количества элементов...

```
printf("\nВведите количество элементов: ");
cin >> n;
list lst(n);
```

Вы же сами вносите его в список!

```
list(int n)
{
    head = new node;
    head->inf = n;
    head->next = nullptr;
}
```

Просто не вносите, только и всего...

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы не вносить, у меня же n символов. Я что-то не пойму как сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Просто не вносить... Ну как вам объяснить, как что-то не делать? Зачем вы вообще при создании списка обязательно что-то в него вносите? Да и потом, это вы считаете 6 - количеством элементов в списке, а на самом деле это просто первый элемент списка.

Comment: Исправила, просто сначала сделала ошибку. Спасибо